# Using jquery tabs function in admin panel in opencart

Tags: jquery, tabs, opencart, admin

Im working on a module in the admin view using opencart.The problem is that im always asked to login to the admin panel.
Everything is loaded properly.

```
<div id="tabs">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#products_tab">Products</a></li>
                <li><a href="#config_tab">Config</a></li>
             </ul>
            <div id="products_tab">
            </div>

            <div id="config_tab">
            </div>
</div>
<script>
 $(function() {
    $("#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you think any one can help you with this code?

Comment: Its very specific problem,I think that someone who has done this in opencart can help!

Comment: I think opencart product edit page already have this code. So others can help you only if you explain more about your issue.

Comment: you are right but the way there seems complicated , I want to use the jquery .tabs() func

Comment: The code you've given doesn't have anything related to the login issue.

Answer (score 0):

i use bootstrap nav pill for my custom controller in open cart and work fine for me:
i add after *breadcrumb* code

```
<ul class="pull-left nav nav-pills nav-justified">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tab1">Tab1 Title</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#tab2">Tab2 Title</a></li>
</ul>
```

and this for content of tabs:

```
   <div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>header text</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body"> text of content </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```